# How to read large data using TcpListener

Tags: c#

I want to read data more than 1024 byte using TcpListener in socket programming. When i try to read data from network stream it breaks into multiple segment.

```cs
const int port = 1200;
this._ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.12");
this._server = new TcpListener(this._ip, port);
this._server.Start();
while (true)
{
    var client = this._server.AcceptTcpClient();
    var remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
    Console.WriteLine(@"Connected");
    this._publicIp = "";
    if (remoteEndPoint != null)
    {
        this._publicIp = remoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
    }
    this._stream = client.GetStream();
    int i = _stream.Read(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);                          
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_bytes, 0, i);
    client.Close();
}
int i = _stream.Read(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_bytes, 0, i);
```

Comment: That is normal and intended. Its a common standard to split it into multible chunks. you should normally concatinate them in your code. Many devices in your network might even be unable to pürocess packages bigger than 1024

Comment: You need to rethink your design, and read until there is no more data and append it together

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it was something to do with using the SendReceiveBuffer

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverTCPPort);
                tcpListener.Start();
                string received = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.SendBufferSize];
                    int recv = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        recv = stream.Read(bytes, 0, tcpClient.SendBufferSize);
                        received += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, recv);

                        if (received.EndsWith("\n\n"))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your code does process multiple chunks of data correctly, you might want to clean up a bit (where does the `writer` come from?) and perhaps explain what's happening.